# Does integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

I have proven it does't converge absolutely, but I'm curious if it converges. So what I've done is $I = \int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}dx$ = $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x (\sqrt x + \sin x)}{x - \sin^2 x}dx$ and because $\frac{1}{x - \sin^2 x}$ is monotonous and periodical integral of $\sin^2 x$ is not equal to $0$, we know that $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x}{x - \sin^2 x}dx$ diverges. Now it's needed to be shown that $\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x\sqrt x}{x - \sin^2 x}dx$ converges, but I'm not sure that's even true. As for absolute converges we know $\left \vert \frac{\sin x (\sqrt x + \sin x)}{x - \sin^2 x} \right \vert \leq \left \vert \frac{\sin x (\sqrt x + \sin x)}{x} \right \vert $, which integral diverges.

Comment: How is $x-\sin^2 x$ monoton*ic*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to the expectations the integral in question is divergent.

Indeed, the integral  $$\int\limits_1^\infty {\sin x\over \sqrt{x}}\,dx$$ is convergent due to the Dirichlet test. Therefore it suffices to study the convergence of the integral of the function $${\sin x\over \sqrt{x}-\sin x}-{\sin x\over \sqrt{x}}={\sin^2x\over (\sqrt{x}-\sin x)\sqrt{x}} \\ \ge {\sin^2x\over (\sqrt{x}+1)\sqrt{x}} \ge {\sin^2x\over (\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x}}={1-\cos(2x)\over 4x}$$ However $$\int\limits_1^\infty {1-\cos(2x)\over 4x}\, dx=\infty$$ because the integral of ${\cos(2x)\over 4x}$ is convergent, while that of ${1\over 4x}$ is divergent. Hence the original integral is divergent.

Comment: ${\sin^2x\over (\sqrt{x}-\sin x)\sqrt{x}} \ge {\sin^2x\over x}$ is not true; the difference between the two sides in fact alternates in sign. I believe it is sufficient to use ${\sin^2x\over (\sqrt{x}-\sin x)\sqrt{x}} \ge \frac{\sin^2x}{\color{red}{2}x}$ though, after which your argument goes through

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks. I will re-edit.

Comment: Very neat. Thanks. Although divergence is exactly what I expected:)

Comment: Thanks. Concerning expectations I was referring to the comments. See the remark at the end: slight modification leads to convergence.

Comment: Also at the step $\int \frac{ \sin^2{x}}{x+ \sqrt{x}}$ it’s already obvious in divergence because $\frac{1}{x+ \sqrt{x}}$ is monotonic and $\int sin^2{x}$ is no equal to 0 by period.

Comment: That's true but the argument requires short explanation, so I preferred to use trigonometry.

Answer (score 3):

The integral is divergent. To see this, let us rewrite it as a series,
$I = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$, where
$$
a_n=\int_{I_n}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}\,dx \tag{1}
$$
and the intervals of integration are $I_0=[1,2\pi]$ and
$I_n=[2n\pi, 2(n+1)\pi]$ for $n\geq 1$. Next, let us rewrite $a_n$
$(n\geq 1)$ as
\begin{align}
a_n&= \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}\,dx
+\int_{(2n+1)\pi}^{(2n+2)\pi}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}\,dx \\
&=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}
+\frac{\sin (x+\pi)}{\sqrt {x+\pi} - \sin (x+\pi)}\right)dx \\
&=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\left(\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt x - \sin x}
-\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt {x+\pi} + \sin x}\right)dx \\
&=\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{(\sqrt{x+\pi}-\sqrt{x}+2\sin x)\sin x}
{\sqrt{x(x+\pi)}+(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+\pi})\sin x - \sin^2x}\,dx. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Since $\sin x\geq 0$ in the interval of integration of $(2)$, the following inequalities are valid there:
$$
(\sqrt{x+\pi}-\sqrt{x}+2\sin x)\sin x \geq 2\sin^2 x \tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{x(x+\pi)}+(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+\pi})\sin x - \sin^2x \leq
\sqrt{x(x+\pi)} < x+\pi. \tag{4}
$$
It follows from these inequalities and $(2)$ that
\begin{align}
a_n&>\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{2\sin^2 x}{x+\pi}\,dx \\
&>\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi+\pi}\int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\sin^2 x\,dx \\
&=\frac{1}{(n+1)\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$ diverges, we conclude that $I=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ also diverges.

Comment: When you got $a_n > \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n + 1)\pi} \frac{2sin^2{x}}{x + \pi}dx >  \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n + 1)\pi} \frac{sin^2{x}}{x}dx$, we can conclude $I > \int_{2\pi}^{\infty} \frac{sin^2{x}}{x}dx$ which diverges.